# Help with Sessions Issues

Tags: php

This just a same script in different server:

The link below works. When you enter the correct characters it display success.

http://mibsolutionsllc.com/captcha_test/test.php

This link below works. Even you enter the correct characters. Display always error. The session value doesn't give function the right way.

http://www.universitywomenshealthcare.com/uwh-content/captcha_test/test.php

If it's a sessions issue, how would one go about fixing this?

Comment: Your first link doesn't work. Even if it did I doubt it would help. It's going to be hard to help you without any kind of meaningful error message or snippet of code. How does one go about fixing a session issue? Debug it like you would anything else. And get in the habit of accepting answers.

Comment: Again, fixing the link doesn't help if all we see is a different message after typing the captcha in. Could a doctor tell exactly what was wrong by comparing you to a healthy person standing next to you?

Comment: Add a .phps so that people can help you debug the code to your external php links.
Or provide code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Try to echo out what the answer is for the input and check your current settings when you are comparing the input vs. the captcha.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put your php code in this page? In your second page (http://www.universitywomenshealthcare.com/uwh-content/captcha_test/test.php), somehow session variable is not keeping the originally assigned captcha value. Have you put session_start() in this second page. We will be able to help you more if you can send these two php pages.